# i am trying to run my emulator on android studio, and i keep getting this adb error

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

Error (could not automatically detect an ADB binary. Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB is added.

This can be done in Extended `controls(...)` > `settings` > `General tab` > 'use detected ADB location'